"symbol not found" when using Lombok
after adding Lombok version 1.18.32 to my Java Project, it doesn't compile any more. I'm using IntelliJ Idea 2023.3.2 and installed the Lombok plugin.
I'm getting "Symbol not found" for all the generated getters and setters.
The errors only show up when building the application.
I tried activating annotation processing in the IntelliJ settings and tried different versions of Lombok, but it didn't help

can you share your pom.xml or build.gradle file ?

it semed like I was missing the annotationProcessor line in the build.gradle file. So I think it's fixed now
